# Wrap specific substrings in HTML tags using a combination of blacklisted words and custom business logic

Tags: php, string, split

I have to deal with plant Latin names and need to style parts of the words in the name of the plants coming from the DB. The names are stored as raw text.

Example string: `Androsace angrenica 'Angelica' subsp. Violaceae`

Desired result: `<em>Androsace angrenica</em> 'Angelica' subsp. <em>Violaceae</em>`

Some specific words are to be excluded from being wrapped in italics tags, like shown in the example above and in the array `$toFind`.

I got so far but ending up with every single word except for the one in the array being wrapped by `<em></em>` like so:

`<em>Androsace</em> <em>angrenica</em> 'Angelica' subsp. <em>Violaceae</em>`

I would like to be able to prevent following `</em> <em>` like in the first part of the name and join them in one single tag wrap shown in the first example.

```php
# Array of words not be wraped in italic
$toFind = ["subsp.", "var.", "f.", "(voir)", "hybride"];

# Plant name
$name = "Androsace angrenica 'Angelica' subsp. Violaceae";

# Make an array of words from the name
$words = explode( " ", $name );

$newWords = [];

foreach( $words as $key => $word ) {
    if( in_array( $word, $toFind )) {
        $newWords[] =  $word;
    }else{
        # Catch the word or words surrounded  by single quotes like 'Angelica'
        $isHybrid = preg_match_all( "/'([^.]*?)'/", $word, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER );

        if( $isHybrid ){
            # No tags required
            $newWords[] = $word ;
        }else{
            # Tags required for these words
            $newWords[] = "<em> ". $word . "</em>";
        }
    }
}

echo implode(" ", $newWords);
```

Note that this example name is one of many possibilities like so:

- `Allium obliquum`
- `Allium ostrowkianum (voir) A. oreophilum`
- `Allium senescens subsp. glaucum`
- `Allium sikkimense`
- `Androsace × pedemontana`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your task logic is a blend of literal and non-literal word exclusions.  The truth is that you don't need to `explode()` the string into a temporary array, compare each word against a blacklist array, then use a regex to conditionally exclude single-quote-wrapped words, then implode the potentially mutated words again.

It will be much more direct to prepare a single regex pattern which specifically matches the first two words then disqualifies later words with a negated lookahead.  Then `preg_replace()` is the best single-call tool to execute your logic.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/JpPZG))

```
$blacklist = ["subsp.", "var.", "f.", "(voir)", "hybride"];
$prepped = array_map('preg_quote', $blacklist);             // escape special characters
$prepped[] = "'\S+'";                                       // do not escape special characters
$negLookAhead = '(?!' . implode('|', $prepped) . ')';       // create negated lookahead
$firstTwoWords = '(?:^\S+\s\S+)';                           // match the first two words of the string
$regex = '#' . $firstTwoWords . '|(?<=\s)' . $negLookAhead . '\S+(?=\s|$)#';

$names = [
    "Androsace angrenica 'Angelica' subsp. Violaceae",
    'Allium obliquum',
    'Allium ostrowkianum (voir) A. oreophilum',
    'Allium senescens subsp. glaucum',
    'Allium sikkimense',
    'Androsace × pedemontana',
];


// echo $regex;

var_export(
    preg_replace($regex, '<em>$0</em>', $names)  // works on an array or a string as input
);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '<em>Androsace angrenica</em> \'Angelica\' subsp. <em>Violaceae</em>',
  1 => '<em>Allium obliquum</em>',
  2 => '<em>Allium ostrowkianum</em> (voir) <em>A.</em> <em>oreophilum</em>',
  3 => '<em>Allium senescens</em> subsp. <em>glaucum</em>',
  4 => '<em>Allium sikkimense</em>',
  5 => '<em>Androsace ×</em> <em>pedemontana</em>',
)
```

Not only is this more direct and more concise, if you want to extend the literal or non-literal exclusions, you don't need to modify the pattern, only the `$prepped` array.

Pattern breakdown:

```
#              // start of pattern delimiter
(?:^\S+\s\S+)  // match two consecutive words if at start of string
|              // OR operator
(?<=\s)        // check that previous character was a whitespace
(?!            // do not allow match to qualify if any of the follow is satisfied
   subsp\.     // literal string match
   |           // OR operator
   var\.       // literal string match
   |           // OR operator
   f\.         // literal string match
   |           // OR operator
   \(voir\)    // literal string match
   |           // OR operator
   hybride     // literal string match
   |           // OR operator
   '\S+'       // single quote, one or more of any non-whitespace character, single quote
)              // close the negated lookahead logic
\S+            // match one or more non-whitespace characters
(?=\s|$)       // check that next character is a whitespace or the next position is the end of string
#              // end of pattern delimiter
```

Comment: Hey @mickmackusa, that is a very interesting approche. I thought of using regex but I am at the basic with it. I tested your solution and it words very good except the hybrid name in single quotes is outputed as \'Angelica\' as if the quotes are kept escaped. Do you have a solution to prevent this? Many thanks

Comment: The combination of the two first solutions do the job perfectly. Thanks to both!

Comment: the hybrid name in single quotes is outputed as \'Angelica\' bevause of the var_export().

Answer (score 1):

You could consider processing the `implode()` result:

```php
echo str_replace("</em> <em>", " ", implode(" ", $newWords));
```

This replaces all instances of `</em> <em>` to   after implosion of the `$newWords`.